# fscanf as a while statement

Tags: c, scanf

hey guys i hope you are all well.

i'm trying to count how many times the fscanf function reads from a file. i couldn't handle for about 2 hours. i couldn't figure out why this happens. in VSCode and CodeBlocks this code snippet works properly.
i'm using c language btw.

```
while(fscanf(fpt,"%d",&numpt)!=EOF)
{
    printf("grayvalues = %d\n",numpt);  
}
```

i'm trying to count how many times loop works by using count variable. and it doesnt even work. could you please help me?

```
int numpt;
int count = 0;
while(fscanf(fpt,"%d",&numpt)!=EOF)
{
 
   
   printf("grayvalues = %d\n",numpt);
   count=count +1;

}
```

source code is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char _name[] = "xc.ascii.pgm";
FILE *fpt;

char* buffp2;
fpt = fopen(_name,"r");

fgets(buffp2,70,fpt);
printf("p2 line will be written = %s\n",buffp2);

fgets(buffp2,70,fpt);
printf("%s\n",buffp2);

int col;
fscanf(fpt,"%d",&col);
printf("%d\n",col);

int row;
fscanf(fpt,"%d",&row);
printf("%d\n",row);

int max_g;
fscanf(fpt,"%d",&max_g);
printf("max gray val = %d\n",max_g);


printf("file matrix elements = \n");

int numpt;
int count = 0;
while(fscanf(fpt,"%d",&numpt)!=EOF)
{
    printf("grayvalues = %d\n",numpt);
// count=count +1;      
// printf("count = %d\n",count);
}

printf("file is read\n");

fclose(fpt);

return 0;

}
```

i have created a pgm file i'm trying to open.

```
P2
# xc.ascii.pgm
24 7
15
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0 3  3  3  3  0  0  7  7 7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11 0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0 3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0 0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0 0  0 15  0  0 15  0
0 3  3  3  0  0  0  7  7 7  0  0  0 11 11 11  0 0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0 3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0 0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0 0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0 3  0  0  0  0  0  7  7 7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11 0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0



file name is xc.ascii.pgm
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". Please provide a [minimal verfiiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: i'm expecting to work until fscanf encounters EOF. and at every step increment count variable. when i try to compile this message is shown.Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))

Comment: Don't add important info that belongs in the question into the comments. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64435511/edit) your question to add such info. Also, as requested please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, a small but complete example that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the exact problem. Include sample input file.

Comment: if i comment count=count+1 line fscanf reads from file. print to a new line. and stops at end of file  without error.

Comment: Third time: [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is what we need.

Comment: `while(fscanf(fpt,"%d",&numpt)==1)` you are looking for `1` VALID conversion. `EOF` is `-1` and will test `true`.

Comment: What do you think will happen with `while(fscanf(fpt,"%d",&numpt)!=EOF) { ... }` when `fscanf()` tries to translate the input `UYszw` into an `int`?  Or any other non-numeric input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparent you are struggling will many aspects of reading input. The key is to validate every step. For starters, do not hardcode Filenames or use *Magic Numbers*. You shouldn't have to re-compile your program just to read from a different file. `70` is a magic number. You can handle both by simply defining a constant and passign the filename to read as an argument to your program. (that's what `int argc, char **argv` parameters to `main()` are for). You can also take the filename as input -- your choice.

For example, you can begin your code with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[MAXC];                             /* buffer to hold each line */
    int row, col, max_g, numpt, count = 0;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fpt = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fpt) { /* validate file open for reading */
        fputs ("error: file open failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** the program will read from the filename given as the first argument to the program or it will read from `stdin` by default if no argument is given. A ternary is used to control whether a file is opened or whether `stdin` is simply assigned to `fpt`)

With your file open for reading -- and validated open, you can begin reading the first line into `buf`. Note `fgets()` reads and includes the `'\n'` with the buffer it fills, so you need to account for that in your output.

```
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fpt)) {              /* read/validate first line */
        fputs ("error: EOF\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("p2 line will be written = %s", buf);
```

Now you can read and discard any comment lines and read the line containing `col` and `row`:

```
    /* read/ignore all comment lines, read col & row line */
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fpt) && *buf == '#')
        printf ("%s", buf);
    
    /* parse col & row from buf */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d", &col, &row) != 2) {
        fputs ("error: invalid row/col format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("col: %d, row: %d\n", col, row);
```

You get the drift, read with `fgets()` and then parse any values you need from the buffer using `sscanf()` (or you can use a pair of pointers to do it manually, or a myriad of string functions from `string.h` to help)

The next line is the max grayscale line, simply follow the normal route of read with `fgets()` and parse with `sscanf()`:

```
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fpt)) {              /* read/validate max grayscale line */
        fputs ("error: EOF\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    /* parse max grayscale from buf */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &max_g) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid max_g format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("max gray val = %d\nfile matrix elements = \n", max_g);
```

Now you have the grayscale values to read. While you could use the `fgets()` and `sscanf()` method and then use `"%n"` to capture the number of characters consumed in each conversion to `int`, it is just as easy here to use `fscanf()` to read until you run out of integer values:

```
    /* read all integer grayscale values */
    while (fscanf (fpt, "%d", &numpt) == 1) {
        int col1 = 0;                           /* flag indicating 1st col in row */
        if (count && count % col == 0) {        /* if not row1 and count % col == 0 */
            col1 = 1;                           /* set 1st col flag */
            putchar ('\n');                     /* output newline */
        }
        /* if 1st col in row, format as "%2d", otherwise " %2d" */
        printf ((!count || col1) ? "%2d" : " %2d", numpt);
        count += 1;                             /* increment count */
    }
    putchar ('\n');             /* tidy up with '\n' */
```

(**note:** the ternary operator is use in the `printf()` format statement to control outputting a space before each 2-digit values from column 2 until the end, while outputting no space before the value for the 1st column. The ternary is simply a shorthand, inline `if .. else` way of controlling things. The `col1` flag just control outputting a `'\n'` before each 1st `col` value is output other than the first row)

Finally, just because you have read and output the grayscale values, that doesn't mean you have the right number, ***validate, validate, validate***:

```
    if (count != col * row) {   /* validate col * row grayscale values read */
        fputs ("error: invalid grayscale count.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("file is read\n");   /* all done */
    
    if (fpt != stdin)           /* close file if not reading stdin */
        fclose (fpt);
}
```

Only output `"file read"` after validating the correct number of `col` & `row` values were read.

**Example Use/Output**

Reading from your file `xc.ascii.pgm`, you would receive the following output.

```
$ ./bin/pgmread dat/xc.ascii.pgm
p2 line will be written = P2
# xc.ascii.pgm
col: 24, row: 7
max gray val = 15
file matrix elements =
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  3  3  3  3  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
 0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0 15  0
 0  3  3  3  0  0  0  7  7  7  0  0  0 11 11 11  0  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
 0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
 0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
file is read
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

With the code

```
char* buffp2;
fpt = fopen(_name,"r");

fgets(buffp2,70,fpt);
```

you're reading into memory using an uninitialized pointer, so it will probably crash.  It never even gets to your while loop.